# Остановить выполнение при закрытии Активити

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Есть класс `ParseJSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>`, который парсит JSON файл и каждые 2 секунды выводит в TextView текст из JSON.

В методе `onResume()` есть такой код, которые каждые 2 сек заново создает объект и заново парсит JSON

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new ParseJSONTask().execute();
    }
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Заметила, что если закрыть активити, то продолжается парсинг JSON. Заметила это когда в классе ParseJSONTask вывела в логи нужный текст и он продолжал выводиться в логи даже когда закрыла активити.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии активити перестало парсить JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В методе `onResume()` есть такой код

Данный код лучше вынести в метод `onStart()`, так как `onResume()` может вызываться несколько раз в процессе того, как Ваше приложение будет на экране (но будет меняться фокус), следовательно, задачи будут выполнятся чаще, чем раз в 2 секунды.

В данном случае нет необходимости в `AsyncTask`, так как Вы и так создаете отдельный поток (при этом не забудьте, что манипулировать UI можно только из UI-треда).

Ресурсы лучше освобождать раньше, чем в методе `onDestroy()`, так как он может не вызваться вообще.

Пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName() + "_TAG";
    private ScheduledFuture<?> mScheduledFuture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mScheduledFuture = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "New task");
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mScheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    }
}
```

Здесь, в методе `onStart()` происходит запуск выполнения задач, а в методе `onStop()` – остановка выполнения задач, соответственно, требуемые действия будут выполняться только в тот момент, когда активити находится на экране.

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что нужно. Мне как нужно было чтобы задача выполнялась только тогда активити открыто.

Answer (score 0):

Надо остановить `AsyncTask`, например вызовом `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`, а еще лучше остановить и `Runnable` внутри которого запущен ваш `AsyncTask`

Лучше всего это посадить в `onDestroy()` вашего `Activity`

Правда, для этого вам придется все ваше хозяйство деанонимизировать

**Update:**

```
private AsyncTask myTask;

Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myTask=new ParseJSONTask();
        myTask.execute();
    }
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   if(myTask!=null)  
      myTask.cancel(true);  //не уверен, что так сработает, может начать ругаться, что нет доступа - в общем идея ясна?
}
```

**Update2**

Читаем доки:

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.

Грубо говоря это означает, что остановка таска не гарантируется. Чтобы гарантировать остановку, вам нужно перегрузить метод `cancel()` в своем таске и предусмотреть в его внутренней логике возможность корректной остановки при вызове этого метода. Типа:

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, а как сделать это? Т.е. остановить потом тоже.  AsyncTask.cancel(true)  на такое компилятор ругается. А то что поток необходимо остановить я понимаю)

Comment: О боже... см. апдейт

Comment: ошибку выбросило Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]

Comment: Девушка, я не компилятор - пишу на коленках и даю лишь общую канву идеи - дальше сами. Разбирайтесь. Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо, но ваш способ не работает. Если даже закрыть активити все равно парсит.

Comment: См. апдейт №2...